# I'm passing my state as props but it is appearing as null. Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 2 components: Locatione.js and Map.js

In Locatione.js I get the location of the user, then I put it in state and I pass it as props in my Map.js component.

The problem is that the props are appearing as null. What am I missing here?

```
export default class Locatione extends Component {
  state = {
    location: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation
    });
    this.setState({ location });
    console.log("log this pls", this.state); // this is logging the right location object
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Map locatione={this.state} /> // when accesing this props in Map, I'm getting **null**
    );
  }
}
```

Here my Map component

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {


componentWillMount() {
  console.log("i want locatione here as props", this.props) // props here appear as null
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be passed as `locatione={this.state.location}`?. Also, `componentWillWount` [should be avoided](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount), try to use `componentDidMount`

Comment: Can you show the Map component?

Answer (score 1):

The `componentWillMount` method is `UNSAFE` in the current version of the react so you shouldn't use it. You have null in the child component because on the first render it is null. The component is re-rendered when you call setState and then you receive new value in children. You should display the map conditionally based on the `this.state.location` or use loading component when the location is null if the map component needs correct value.